# however vs in comparison

Tags: word-choice, difference

A native English speaker wrote this sample paragraph about the two pie charts for me to study. Why is "however" used? What I've learned is that "however" expresses a comparison that contains a suggestion of the difference being unexpected. But there is nothing unexpected about the increase in spending on technology. I wonder if "in comparison" would be better?

> *Expenditure primarily consisted of officer and staff salaries, although the proportion decreased from 75% of the total to 69%. **However**, spending on technology almost doubled to 14% from 8%, whilst expenditure on buildings and transport remained constant at 17%.*

[image]

Comment: The increase in spending on technology is _in contrast to_ the decrease in spending on salaries. The difference doesn't have to be unexpected.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does "in comparison" work in that paragraph? Also, I was told by a native speaker that in this situation, "in comparison" instead of "however" should be used: China produced 5,398 billion kWh of electricity. Germany, in comparison, only produced 526.6 billion kWh. Why is "however" wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why your informant considered _however_ to be wrong in that sentence. You could use _in comparison_ in the passage about the police.

Comment: Note that **however** can often be replaced with **but** whilst retaining the same meaning. As an aside  I would suggest your example should say _almost doubled from 8% t0 14%_  to be easier to read for a native BrE speaker..